# wifi broadcast receiver multiple intents

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I have developped an application using Wifi broadcast receiver. My requirement is get function call when Wifi is connected to a router by obtaining the IP address as well as call another function when Wifi is disconnected from previously connected router.

**I used this in Manifest**

```
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
```

for registering broadcast receiver.

and in Broadcast Receiver class in `OnReceive` :

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
NetworkInfo.State state = networkInfo.getState(); 

if (state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    Log.e("++++WiFi Conected","++++WiFi Conected");

    Flags.wifiState = true;
    updateWifiSyncTrue(context);

    if (wi.getIpAddress() != 0) {
        intent = new Intent(context, ConnectionService.class);
        intent.putExtra("intentValue", "signalOn");
        intent.putExtra("bssId", wi.getBSSID());
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}

if (state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
    Log.e("++++WiFi DisConected","++++WiFi DisConnected");
    Flags.wifiState = false;
    updateWifiSyncFalse(context);
    updateRouterSyncFalse(context);

    intent = new Intent(context, ConnectionService.class);
    intent.putExtra("intentValue", "signalOff");
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

---

**Every thing worked till KitKat**
But when I test this with lollipop version On Receive call many times for.

**When I turn my WiFi on its resulting** as
State : 
*Idle --Connecting-- Authenticating -- Captive Check -- Connected -- Connected .
Sometimes Disconnected also.*

**while turning off.**
*Connected -- Disconnected -- Disconnected -- Disconnected -- Disconnected*

**The Debug result of `NetworkInfo` is as below:**

```
[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/CONNECTING, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/AUTHENTICATING, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/AUTHENTICATING, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/CONNECTING, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/OBTAINING_IPADDR, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "DJ     Hostspot", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false].
```

I kindly request to help me in the same. Using my code when wifi is turned on `CONNECTED` state is executing multiple times and `DISCONNECTED` state also.

And when WIFI is turned off Connected state is generated and then 4-5 Disconnected State.

I Used HTC phone for testing.

I used simple coding, Do I have to get more deeper condition checking for this? (Detailed State etc...)

What is the best way to handle this solution ?

Comment: Thank for the edit and corrections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ever you are using intent-filter `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE` it will trigger the broadcast receiver multiple times. For example if you are switching on wifi then the `onreceive` of the broadcast will call multiple times anywhere from 1-5 times. So, it will give you multiple `NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED` and same with disconnected also.

So if you want to have only one connected or disconnected it output means simply use a boolean flag and set it properly in a way that first if wifi enabled comes means it should ignore remaining wifi connected intents and similarly wifi disconnected also.